# How to convert a normal web application to a multi-lingual web application using Java?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am having a normal web application which I have created using JSP and servlets. Previously it s purpose to serve only one language i.e english but now it needs to serve clients with various languages such as spanish, french etc.

So, how can I achieve this

Regards,
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simplest way of acheiving this is to get the browser locale and and then get specific properties on the basis of that locale.
So for instance your browser locale is set to French then you would pick names of all your labels defined in JSP's from _fr properties file. I am just giving directions/pointers.

Make sense?

Thanks, KJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frameworks such as Spring, Struts or Seam then they provide various classes to support i18n, you need to explore.

If you not using any such framework then you should read [Java Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/).

Comment: I have read it, but can you suggest some videos which explains it well ?